# Get data from 3 tables using UNION ALL

Tags: postgresql

I have these tables to which I am doing a query to get data from all the tables

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e8d847e118b372071e42c685e9e5ad72

In the sample, there is not a lot of data but I am looking for a way to paginate the data results of the UNION ALL query.

```
select
    C.EXID as CAMERA_ID,
    U.EMAIL,
    TRIM(CONCAT(U.FIRSTNAME, ' ', U.LASTNAME)),
    ARC.TITLE,
    ARC.EXID,
    ARC.CREATED_AT,
    ARC.FROM_DATE,
    ARC.TO_DATE,
    null as EMBED_CODE,
    ARC.FILE_NAME,
    ARC.FRAMES,
    ARC.URL,
    ARC.PUBLIC,
    ARC.STATUS,
    ARC.TYPE,
    null as EXTRA
from
    PUBLIC.ARCHIVES as ARC
left join USERS U on
    ARC.REQUESTED_BY = U.ID
left join CAMERAS C on
    ARC.CAMERA_ID = C.ID
union all
select
    C.EXID as CAMERA_ID,
    U.EMAIL,
    TRIM(CONCAT(U.FIRSTNAME, ' ', U.LASTNAME)),
    TL.TITLE,
    TL.EXID,
    TL.INSERTED_AT,
    TL.FROM_DATETIME,
    TL.TO_DATETIME,
    null as EMBED_CODE,
    null as FILE_NAME,
    null as FRAMES,
    null as URL,
    null as PUBLIC,
    TL.STATUS,
    null as type,
    TL.EXTRA
from
    PUBLIC.TIMELAPSES as TL
left join USERS U on
    TL.USER_ID = U.ID
left join CAMERAS C on
    TL.CAMERA_ID = C.ID
union all
select
    C.EXID as CAMERA_ID,
    U.EMAIL,
    TRIM(CONCAT(U.FIRSTNAME, ' ', U.LASTNAME)),
    COMP.EXID,
    COMP.NAME,
    COMP.INSERTED_AT,
    COMP.BEFORE_DATE,
    COMP.AFTER_DATE,
    COMP.EMBED_CODE,
    null as FILE_NAME,
    null as FRAMES,
    null as URL,
    COMP.PUBLIC,
    COMP.STATUS,
    null as type,
    null as EXTRA
from
    PUBLIC.COMPARES as COMP
left join USERS U on
    COMP.REQUESTED_BY = U.ID
left join CAMERAS C on
    COMP.CAMERA_ID = C.ID;
```

Comment: Take a look at [mcve] for details about how to post a question that provides all the details necessary for a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there's no way that you can avoid using a `UNION [ALL]` in this case. Your `timelapses`, `compares` and `archives` tables are connected to `users` and to `cameras` but not to each other, so in order to link them, we have no choice but to use a `UNION`.

I played around a wee bit (with a subset of the fields) and I came up with this which may help (all the code below is in a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a882fbd009ee3e69e1b714abcb64829c)):

```
WITH core AS (
  SELECT 
    'Archives' AS tab_name, a.id, a.exid, LEFT(a.title, 10) AS title, a.camera_id, a.requested_by
  FROM archives a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Compares', c.id, c.exid, RIGHT(name, 10), c.camera_id, c.requested_by
  FROM compares c
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Timelapse', t.id, t.exid, t.title, t.camera_id, t.user_id
  FROM timelapses t)
SELECT * FROM core;
```

Result:

```
tab_name    id  exid    title   camera_id   requested_by
Archives    1   concre-r6ys     Concrete P  1   1
Archives    2   201809-27xn     2018-09-26  1   1
Archives    3   201902-htu9     2019-02-01  4   1
...
...
...
Archives    9   spark-kyzrq     Sparks Bui  1   1
Archives    10  201611-luw8     2016-11-06  2   4
Compares    1   compa-ylxwctg   o 29th Oct  1   2
Compares    2   test-hroqe      test        2   3
...
...
```

So, we can see that in the combined data, we have a way of getting at the source table name - by selecting it as a `TEXT` string at the beginning.

You can add in `users` info (like email, firstname, lastname) and `cameras` by JOINING to this "core" - see fiddle.

You can search now by doing something like this (again, see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a882fbd009ee3e69e1b714abcb64829c)):

```
...
... core CTE query
...
)
SELECT * FROM core
WHERE title LIKE '%Pond%';
```

Result:

```
tab_name    tab_id         exid     title      camera_id    requested_by
Timelapse        1  longp-mvxla     Long Ponds         1               2
```

So, now we know that the photo with the title "Long Ponds" is in the Timelapse table and it's id in that table is 1.

A few words of advice:

- I would consolidate my (photograph) tables - this will make matters considerably easier. There should be some combination of fields that is `UNIQUE` - and you can keep the tab_name field (and use it to enforce uniqueness).
- you have some field names (location, type...) as quoted identifiers. This should be avoided - use t_type... something with an underscore - which remains legible but isn't an [SQL keyword](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words).

  If you decide to consolidate, you can have `NULL`s where there isn't a corresponding field in the other tables.
- a note on performance: As you can see from the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` at the end of the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a882fbd009ee3e69e1b714abcb64829c), your `UNION` plan has more than twice as many operations as my `more_info` table - this is because I perform the `JOIN` on `users` and `cameras` only once for all the photos whereas you do it three times.

  However you decide to do it - via sub-queries or CTEs, only doing it once is the better option. You could wrap your original `UNION`s (without `JOIN`s) in a `SELECT` and `JOIN` on that if you prefer... YMMV...

I know that this probably isn't the outcome you hoped for, but I hope this has helped a little - best of luck with your project - agus  slán go fóill a chara!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124858/discussion-between-verace-and-junaid-farooq).